# How can I visulize a spherical texture map on a 3D globe?

Tags: 3d

Imagine I create a 3D texture map. Let's say I'm flexible as to how exactly it's represented on disk, the point is I have something that assigns a number or RGB triplet of numbers to every point on a sphere. Is there any free software on Linux that I can use to visualize this on a globe? I'd like to still be able to see things like country borders and names, but have my texture map overlaid on the globe at 50% opacity. I'd like to be able to interact with the visualization, zooming in and out and turning the globe.

Comment: Most GIS use is about the analysis itself; not many users have spherical surfaces on which to drape their plots, so I doubt there's much development around this. I've seen exactly one display like this, in a science museum, and it probably took some major underwriting to complete (there were dozens of projectors to illuminate portions of the surface; the optics would have to be incredible).

Comment: @Vince Er... no, I was picturing more like a virtual 3D *model* of a globe, not a literal physical one with projectors.